# How to visualize a count of all values in an array field in Kibana

Tags: logstash, visualization, kibana

I am having trouble creating a particular type of visualization in Kibana. My events in Kibana are statistics on communications between two ip address. Two of the fields are lists of ports used by the particular ip address. An example of the fields would be:

```
ip1 = 192.168.101.2
ip2 = 192.168.101.3
ip2Ports = 80,443
ip1Ports = 80,57000,0
```

I would like to have a top count of all the values such as

```
port    count
80      2
57000   1
443     1
```

I have been able to parse ip2Ports to be ip2Ports_List.column1, ip2Ports_List.column2, ect, but I can only choose one term with term aggregation in the visualization. I can split the chart, but that leads to separate counts for each field. If I go by the original ip2Ports field, it is just aggregated as the string such as, "80,443".

Is it even possible to create a top count visualization of fields with multiple values? If so, how would I do so. If not, is there a way to restructure my data so I can do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue stemmed from the **format of the values** being sent in by Logstash. I had thought that the 'ip2Ports_List.column1' format, which was a result from using the csv filter, was part of an array. It wasn't. After analyzing it, 'ip2Ports_List.column1' didn't seem to be much different from a new field.

Elastic **needed an array** to give me the visualization I wanted. I wasn't sure what the best way to produce it was, so I just ended up using the ruby filter. This is what the code ended up looking like:

```
ruby {
  code => "fields = event.get('portsIp').split(',')
  event.set('portsIpArray',fields)"
}
```

Where 'portsIp' looked something like "80,443". Splitting it turned 'portsIp' into a **Ruby array**. I just set that array as the value for a new event field, 'portsIpArray'.

From there when I tried visualize the 'portsIpArray' field, it looked exactly how I wanted it to, treating each port as separate value, and still associating each port with the same event/field.

**Extra:**
Also something I discovered is if you're writing your code like I was, directly in the Logstash conf file, Logstash doesn't like it if you use double quotes within the double quoted code. In hindsight it makes sense, but it doesn't give a clear error so it's difficult to figure out.